# Dynamically create type based on nested interface property

Tags: typescript

Given the following setup:

```js
enum FormGroups {
  customer = 'customer',
  address = 'address',
}

interface Customer {
  'firstName': string;
}

interface Address {
  'street': string;
}

interface SomeFormEvent {
  valid: boolean;
  forms: {
    [FormGroups.customer]: {
      values: Customer,
    },
    [FormGroups.address]: {
      values: Address,
    }
  }
}
```

Now the following is what I would like to use:

```js
type Forms = Customer | Address
```

However, this is static. If in the future a form is added in the SomeFormEvent like:

```js
interface SomeFormEvent {
  valid: boolean;
  forms: {
    [FormGroups.customer]: {
      values: Customer,
    },
    [FormGroups.address]: {
      values: Address,
    },
    // a form is added here:
    [FormGroups.preferences]: {
      values: Preferences,
    },
  }
}
```

I'd have to manually update the 'Forms' type:

```js
// manually have to add 'Preferences'
type Forms = Customer | Address | Preferences
```

Is there a more dynamic way to create the Forms type?

I've tried the following:

```js
enum FormGroups {
  customer = 'customer',
  address = 'address',
}

interface Customer {
  'firstName': string;
}

interface Address {
  'street': string;
}


interface SomeFormEvent {
  valid: boolean;
  forms: {
    [FormGroups.customer]: {
      values: Customer,
    },
    [FormGroups.address]: {
      values: Address,
    },
  }
}

type Forms = { [K in keyof SomeFormEvent['forms']]: SomeFormEvent['forms'][K]['values'] }

function foo(): Forms {
    return {
        // error: Type '{ firstName: string; street: string; }' is 
        //   not assignable to type 'Forms'. Object literal may only 
        //   specify known properties, and 'firstName' does not exist 
        //   in type 'Forms'.

        firstName: 'sdfdsf',
        street: 'sdffds'
    }
}
```

But that does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, we can create this union using *indexed access types*.

```
type Forms = SomeFormEvent["forms"][keyof SomeFormEvent["forms"]]["values"]
//   ^? Customer | Address
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAYg9gJwgcQXMAHAzlA3gWACgooBjMLAFzgmASgF4oBycqmu5gGiJIEMAJgITAsOJs0HDRWbkQC+RIgEsQlOgDM+pYFADCFarXoFiLDcoRUAcn1rMAXFCoJVAcwDcCpYVXqEWjpQAIJCImJ4vCwuwMCUjs6UriCe3oQqapraugDKHPBIAKIAbqCUkWbFfAA2ygJOAEZwcNXAfCBeZhqIEFhOpiQkANoFKGiYWAB0bEZ0ALr9UYNQVdVgok4G7MY8ZiTyu8sjPajo2JNS4VgLFcskq+t9IWEyh4OKZh8fRJQAnhi6UbiKB5WijEplIYAIm6SCwULmQwA1sBfnANCD8j0IWpobDegjEVCHqIEUA)